# How to compress a directory in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

I know how to open up a zip file in write mode in Elixir:

`file = File.open("myzip.zip", [:write, :compressed])`

but after this, say if I have a directory `/home/lowks/big_files`, how do I write this into `file` ?

Comment: I can't write a more detailed response but you probably want to look at erlang's [zip](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/zip.html) and [zlib](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/zlib.html) modules.

Answer (score 10):

If you are operating on zip files, you'll need to use `:zip.extract('foo.zip')`, and `:zip.create(name, [{'foo', file1data}, file2path, ...])`.

`:zip.create` takes a name, and a list which can contain either of two options:

1. A tuple containing a file name, and binary data to zip.
2. A path to a file to zip.

`:zip.extract` can either take a path to a file, or binary data representing the zip archive (perhaps from doing `File.open` on a zip).

You can do something like the following to take a list of files in a path and zip them up:

```
files = File.ls!(path)
        |> Enum.map(fn filename -> Path.join(path, filename) end)
        |> Enum.map(&String.to_char_list!/1)

:zip.create('foo.zip', files)
```

Comment: Just keeping up a little with the latest syntax: ```iex(1)> File.ls!("/tmp") |>
...(1)> Enum.map(fn filename -> Path.join("/tmp", filename) end) |> 
...(1)> Enum.map&(String.to_char_list!(&1))```

Comment: Also, if you want to specify a directory, you can do something like this: `:zip.create("./my/folder/foo.zip", files)`

Answer (score 2):

This is a fairly good answer, but here is a better one that supports recursively adding directories to the zip from a location.

```
  files = create_files_list(path)
  :zip.create(to_charlist(zip_file_path), files)
```

And here is create_files_list:

```
  defp create_files_list(path) do
    create_files_list(File.ls!(path), path)
  end
  defp create_files_list(paths, path) do
    create_files_list(paths, path, path)
  end
  defp create_files_list(paths, path, base_path) do
    Enum.reduce(paths, [],
      fn(filename, acc) ->
        filename_path = Path.join(path, filename)
        if File.dir?(filename_path) do
          acc ++ create_files_list(File.ls!(filename_path), filename_path, base_path)
        else
          filenm = 
            if base_path, 
              do: String.replace_leading(filename_path, base_path, ""), 
              else: filename_path
          [{String.to_char_list(filenm), File.read!(filename_path)} | acc]
        end
      end
    )
  end
```

A word of warning; I'm not using this for anything very large, it might break everything by using File.read here.  I'm not sure how to use File handles but I think it's possible.  Feel free to improve and contribute back ;-)

I also cache the zip file so it isn't executed every time.